# Connecting to Oracle Spatial from QGIS on Ubuntu

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, oracle-spatial

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and the QGIS from the Ubuntu repo is 3.10.4.

The QGIS does not have any Oracle datasource available, despite of https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html#connecting-to-oracle-spatial

I see there PostGIS, MSSQL etc, but no Oracle.

I am using Oracle 11.2.

Comment: you will need the oracle client installed see https://qtibia.com/build/

Comment: Do you have an Oracle client on your Ubuntu server ?

Comment: Thanks Albert and Mapperz. I will install the client and report back.